# Confusion in variable scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a function in js which populates a global array with values fetched as json from the server script:

```
function populateValues(id) {
    var values=new Array();

    $.getJSON(
        '<?PHP echo base_url();?>admin/forums/getForumById/' + id ,
        function(data){
            $.each(data,function(k,v){
                values.push(v);
            });
            alert(values[1]);
        }
    );
}
```

This works fine and alerts the desired value. But when i try to alert this after the loop, the values are lost and i get a undefined. Here is the case:

```
function populateValues(id) {
    var values=new Array();

    $.getJSON(
        '<?PHP echo base_url();?>admin/forums/getForumById/' + id ,
        function(data){
            $.each(data,function(k,v){
                values.push(v);
            });
        }
    );
    alert(values[1]);
}
```

Is it due to some closure construct forming? Or is it some fundamental concept i am lacking? Just curious to know why the values are not alerted even when i declared the array as global. Please shed some light.

Comment: The problem isn't scope, it's asynchronicity.

Comment: `But when i try to alert this after the loop` Your alert is outside the loop in both examples. The only difference is that example 1 is inside the `get` and example 2 is outside it, hence the asynchronicity issue.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Correct! Sorry by loop i meant the ajax construct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem isn't scope.

The problem is that you're making an AJAX call and then immediately continuing to the next statement before the AJAX call completes.

Therefore, you `alert(values[1]);` before the array is filled from the AJAX call.

Comment: so its something due to non-blocking nature of js :) Thanks a ton. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

This will fix it, using the Promise object returned by the AJAX call:

```
function populateValues(id)
{
    var values=new Array();

    $.getJSON('<?PHP echo base_url();?>admin/forums/getForumById/'+id,function(data){
        $.each(data,function(k,v) {
            values.push(v);
        });
    }).done(function() { alert(values[1]); });
}
```

Comment: Would the alert not always work just fine immediately after the each function? Like in ops first example